# Read rtmp live streaming vido data using java code

Tags: java, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

My requirement is that How to read and create mp4 file from live stream video URL.

I have did many R&D's for this topic but failed to get any answer.
Following link also not useful to me. When I run ffmpeg command given in this question, it gives me an exception.

[I want to use FFMPEG, not xuggle library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879121/how-can-i-read-a-live-webstream-in-java-using-xuggle-i-can-do-it-in-ffmpeg-ju)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the java method which you can use to read data from rtmp url with the integration of FFMPEG library.

```
   public static void liveRtmpFeed() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i",
                "rtmp://192.168.0.90/oflaDemo/livestream", "-ss", "00:00:00",
                "-t", "00:00:10", "-c", "copy", "/home/outputVideo.mp4");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while ((br.readLine()) != null)
            ;
        process.waitFor();

        try {
            process.destroy();
            isr.close();
            stderr.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```