# FFMPEG RTMP not working in my red5pro module on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: ffmpeg, red5pro

This following command not working in my java module (this takes snap from live stream and save it)
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i \"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2\" -f image2 -vframes 1 /snaps/testo.jpg");

If I use same command on Ubuntu 14.0.4 console it works. Same command working in my red5pro module on Window but not on Ubuntu.

When I use
String[] execStr = {"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg","-i","rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest","live=1","timeout=2","-f","image2","-vframes","1","/snaps/tt.jpg"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2 -f image2 -vframes 1 /snaps/testo.jpg");

It always throw stream not found ( in red5pro console)

Comment: I think your problem is `"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest","live=1","timeout=2"`. You probably combine this to one parameter as `"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2"`

Comment: I think I did try that but let me try it again

Comment: now when I do that I get following error
--->RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
--->rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Try this too: `rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest?live=1&timeout=2`

Comment: Now said: --->rtmp server sent error
Following is my code

String[] execStr = {"/usr/bin/ffmpeg", "-i", "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest?live=1&timeout=2", "-f", "image2" ,"-vframes", "1" ,"/snaps/ff.jpg"};
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execStr);   
   pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
   Process p = pb.start();
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   String line2 = null;
   while ((line2 = in.readLine()) != null) 
   {
    System.out.println("--->"+line2);
   }
   if (p.waitFor() == 0) 
   {
    
   }

Comment: ok finally: `"\"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2\""`

Comment: >"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest?live=1&timeout=2": No such file or directory

Comment: Did you try this double quoted (") version here, inner quotes are escaped with (\") ?: `"\"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2\""`

Comment: This is what I have used
String[] execStr = {"/usr/bin/ffmpeg", "-i", "\"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest?live=1&timeout=2\"", "-f", "image2" ,"-vframes", "1" ,"/snaps/ff.jpg"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execStr); but error is No such file or directory
Now please read following points:
(1)same command works when I fire on Ubuntu console. Even this works in php shell_exec(command) on same ubuntu machine.Same command also works on my window machine.

I am thanking you for all your help. If you could get it work then it will be big help for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java (except a little, I'm experienced with FFmpeg) but I think you should write the code like this:

```
String[] execStr = {"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "-i", "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest", "live=1", "timeout=2", "-f", "image2", "-vframes", "1", "/snaps/tt.jpg"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execStr);
```

or like this:

```
String[] execStr = {"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", "-i", "\"rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytest live=1 timeout=2\"", "-f", "image2", "-vframes", "1", "/snaps/tt.jpg"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(execStr);
```

I checked from here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I did try that. You mentioned that spaces among every parameter and yes I tried that but no luck.
Same problem here mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909434/read-rtmp-live-streaming-vido-data-using-java-code

Comment: I will have to work for it but following were errors
rtmp sent errors.
NetStrea.Play.StreamNotFound.
No such directory exist ( this when we use quote).
Invalid header found connection close ( this when we do not use live=1 that says stream is live)